# Old date comparison handling in new MySQL

Tags: mysql

The migration guide for MySQL 5.0 says that the way comparisons are done between DATEs and DATETIMEs has changed.

> Incompatible change: Beginning with MySQL 5.0.42, when a DATE value is compared with a DATETIME value, the DATE value is coerced to the DATETIME type by adding the time portion as 00:00:00. Previously, the time portion of the DATETIME value was ignored, or the comparison could be performed as a string comparison. To mimic the old behavior, use the CAST() function to cause the comparison operands to be treated as previously. For example:

So for example "select ... where my_date < now()" now do DATETIME comparisons (which would include today at 00:00:00) and used to do DATE comparisons (which would not include today).

Is there e.g. a MySQL config option which enables the old behaviour? I couldn't find any yet but that doesn't necessarily mean it isn't there.

We have > 100 KLOC of code with multiple SQL statements regarding billing which all rely on the old date processing.

Comment: This won't be of any help to you, but I wonder why you were allowed to compare a DATE against a DATETIME in the first place.  If they are two different types, you should have been forced to cast one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rely on the billing system I would not even contemplate upgrading the database without a major rewrite.

For a start things like date processing, which is always problematic, need to be moved out of the general code to somewhere specific where they can be more easily managed. Nobody really does date processing well and you need to be insulated from future changes. So fixing it now will help you next time. You may even contemplate moving the date calculations out of the database and firmly into your control (i.e. in code) *but* this may not be feasible for your system.

Secondly, if you don't already have one I would create a rigorous regression testing suite so you can find all the other little (and not so little) things that break. This is critical if you do find a "setting" as the exact behaviour may be more subtle than you may like.

These upgrades are a pain, *especially* when they fix things. Sometimes it is better to just stays with what works until you need to move for other, better reasons.